# leaflet - Changing marker node icon

Tags: javascript, image, icons, leaflet, geojson

This is the GeoJSON point I have:

```json
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      "-83.882517",
      "32.55514717"
    ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "popupContent": "\u003cb\u003eStart OS:(2018-01-25-06.10.46.140000 )\u003c/b\u003e\u003cbr/\u003e(-83.882517, 32.55514717)\u003cbr/\u003e",
    "style": {
      "radius": 8,
      "weight": 1,
      "color": "#000033",
      "fillColor": "#FFFF00",
      "opacity": 1,
      "fillOpacity": 1
    },
    "icon": null
  },
  "id": 5001
},
```

Now, as you see the element has `"icon": null`. How can I access the specific element and change its icon (with something like `XXX.setIcon(trainIcon);`)?

I don't understand how to access the single element and change some of its values. All the feature points are part of the same layer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have GeoJSON data that you display on a Leaflet map by feeding it to [`L.geoJSON`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) factory.

But in some cases, your GeoJSON data does not specify a proper `icon` in the Feature properties, hence you would like to modify those.

Of course the ideal would be to fix your GeoJSON data beforehand, instead of trying to fix the situation at runtime. But if for whatever reason you cannot modify the GeoJSON data, you still have several possible solutions with Leaflet:

1. Use the [`onEachFeature`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-oneachfeature) option of `L.geoJSON` factory, test if the `feature.properties.icon` is incorrect, then reassign the marker icon.
2. Use the [`eachLayer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-eachlayer) method of your already created `L.geoJSON` Layer Group, test if the `layer.feature.properties.icon` is incorrect, then reassign the marker icon.

Since your Features also have an ID, if you know the ID of the Features you need to rework, you could also test for this ID instead of `properties.icon`.

Comment: The goal is trying to modify the icon based on a timer event, that's why I cannot modify the GeoJSON file.
I tried to use `layer.feature.properties.icon` to re-assign a different icon, but for some reason it doesn't work.

How Can I reassign the value? By simply assigning `layer.feature.properties.icon = myIcon`?

Comment: @gabe91 you need to call the `setIcon(yourIcon)` method on the marker object. Reassigning the `layer.feature.properties.icon` won't have an effect because it's only changing the object within your geoJSON. The geoJSON and the marker/icon object/layer operate independently of one another besides marker instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

While ideally you would have your geoJSON configured to return at least the initial icon, you can handle this by keeping track of your `L.marker` objects in a collection, and then calling `setIcon()` when you need to update the icon.

So let's say you create the marker like this:

```
const myMarker = L.marker(latlng, {
            'icon': L.icon({
              iconUrl: /example.png
              iconSize: [37, 37],     
              iconAnchor: [18, 37],    correspond to marker's location
            })
          }).addTo(myMap);
```

Then you can call `myMarker.setIcon(newIcon)` on your timer event.